# Need help in finalizing this Best Fit Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Excuse me, quick question:

I am using the below routine to find all *Combinations* of integers that their sum is equal or less than some integer K.

Imagine I have a glass with volume K, and some beer bottles. I am trying to know which bottles I can pick, and get as much beer as possible!

```
let K = 4; // my glass
let Input = [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 0.75, 3, 4]; // beer bottles
let allCombinations = [];

for(var i = 0; i < Input.length; i++)
{
    let currentCombination = [];

    if(Input[i] <= K)
        currentCombination.push(Input[i]);

    let difference = K - Input[i];

    for(var j = i + 1; j < Input.length; j++)
    {
        if(Input[j] <= difference)
        {
            currentCombination.push(Input[j]);
            difference -= Input[j];
        }
    }
    allCombinations.push(currentCombination);
}
```

**Input:**

> K = 4
>
> [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 0.75, 3, 4]

**Current Output:**

> [1, 2, 0.5]
>
> [2, 0.5, 1.5]
>
> [0.5, 1.5, 2]
>
> [1.5, 2]
>
> [2, 0.75]
>
> [0.75, 3]
>
> [3]
>
> [4]

But I want more beer choices! Some combinations are not included:

**Expected Output:**

> All the above, plus:
>
> [1, 2, 1.5]
>
> [1, 2, 0.75]
>
> [2, 0.5, 0.75]
>
> [2, 2]
>
> [1, 3]
>
> etc ..

Comment: FYI, this sounds like the knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem I guess its simpler if don't need to maximize the amount of beer, and simply want to enumerate all possibilities. Then it's a simple n^2 search, isn't it? Start with one beer, try adding every other beer that doesn't overflow it, and repeat.

Comment: ^ SUPER! Thanks! Later I will add "weight" values for each input item. Would knapsack problem returns ALL combinations and not just the best one?

Comment: The problem with the knapsack problem is that there is *no* fast solution. It's NP-complete. Whether you're finding the best one or all of them doesn't matter -- the only way to solve it is by iterating all solutions. I was wrong when I said "n^2". It's n! (n factorial) I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is suboptimal, but you could use a recursive algorithm that produces all possible permutations, checks each one to determine if it's a unique combination, and adds unique solutions to a solution list:

```js
  combinations = [];
  function getCombinationsLessThan(currentCombination, choices, remainingSum) {

    // Check if currentCombination should be added to the solutions list
    if (remainingSum < 0) {
      return      // Sum is too large; terminate recursion
    } else if (currentCombination.length > 0) {

      currentCombination.sort();    // Sort all combinations so comparison can be made sequentially
      var uniquePermutation = true;

      for (var i=0; i<combinations.length; i++) {

        if (currentCombination.length == combinations[i].length) {

          for (var j=0; currentCombination[j]==combinations[i][j] && j<combinations[i].length; j++);  // Pass

          if (j == currentCombination.length) {
            // For loop got all the way through combinations[i], so currentCombination = combinations[i]
            uniquePermutation = false;
            break;
          }

        }
      }

      if (uniquePermutation) {
        combinations.push(currentCombination);
      }

    }

    for (var i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {

      // Copy choices
      var newChoices = choices.slice();           

      // Cut out the i'th element and add to the current combination
      var newCombination = currentCombination.concat(newChoices.splice(i,1));

      var newRemainingSum = remainingSum - choices[i];
      getCombinationsLessThan(newCombination, newChoices, newRemainingSum);
    
    }
  }

  var k = 4;
  var choices = [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 0.75, 3, 4];
  getCombinationsLessThan([], choices, k);
  
  var result = '';
  for (var i=0; i<combinations.length; i++) {
    result += combinations[i] + '\n';
  }
  console.log(result);
```

This produces the following result:

```js
1
1,2
0.5,1,2
0.75,1,2
0.5,1
0.5,1,1.5
0.5,0.75,1,1.5
0.5,0.75,1
1,1.5
0.75,1,1.5
0.75,1
1,3
2
0.5,2
0.5,1.5,2
0.5,0.75,2
1.5,2
2,2
0.75,2
0.5
0.5,1.5
0.5,0.75,1.5
0.5,0.75
0.5,3
1.5
0.75,1.5
0.75
0.75,3
3
4
```

Comment: ciq, you are needed. Can I have a minute please?

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  This does sound like the knapsack problem: determine if excluding or including an item in the knapsack results in a higher value that does not exceed the capacity of the container.